# Sum column values after grouping

Tags: mysql, date

Please I need some guide on how to sum my **NewConverts** column as seen in the table below.

I have 2 tables with names **tbl_cmleader** and **tbl_cmreport**. I combine the 2
tables to run this query as seen below:

```
SELECT mdate AS MDate, WEEK(mdate) AS MWeek,  WEEK(NOW()) AS CWeek, nconvt AS 
NewConverts, tbl_cmreport.cml_id, tbl_cmleader.grp_id FROM tbl_cmreport INNER JOIN 
tbl_cmleader ON tbl_cmreport.mem_id = tbl_cmleader.mem_id WHERE tbl_cmleader.grp_id = 12 
and mdate = '2022-07-08' ORDER BY mdate DESC
```

After running this query, I get the result as seen below:

| MDate | MWeek | CWeek | NewConverts | cml_id | grp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 5 | 142 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 5 | 142 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 5 | 142 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 143 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 143 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 143 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 143 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 143 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 131 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 131 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 131 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 131 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 131 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 132 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 132 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 132 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 132 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 132 | 12 |

However, I can't use this result to achieve what I want because the values are much. So
I add a **Group By** to help reduce the contents and give me the right values as seen in the query below.

```
SELECT mdate AS MDate, WEEK(mdate) AS MWeek,  WEEK(NOW()) AS CWeek, nconvt AS 
NewConverts, tbl_cmreport.cml_id, tbl_cmleader.grp_id FROM tbl_cmreport INNER JOIN 
tbl_cmleader ON tbl_cmreport.mem_id = tbl_cmleader.mem_id WHERE tbl_cmleader.grp_id = 12 
and mdate = '2022-07-08' GROUP BY mdate, tbl_cmleader.cml_id ORDER BY mdate DESC
```

At the end I get this results below

| MDate | MWeek | CWeek | NewConverts | cml_id | grp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 5 | 142 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 143 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 131 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 132 | 12 |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 1 | 134 | 12 |

This is the final table I want. Now from this table, I want to **SUM** the
**NewConverts** column to get a value of **9** but instead I am getting **36**.

I run this query below to **SUM** the **NewConverts** column. The value I expect after the summation is a **9** but instead I am getting **36**.

```
SELECT mdate AS MDate, WEEK(mdate) AS MWeek,  WEEK(NOW()) AS CWeek, SUM(nconvt) AS 
NewConverts, tbl_cmreport.cml_id, tbl_cmleader.grp_id FROM tbl_cmreport INNER JOIN 
tbl_cmleader ON tbl_cmreport.mem_id = tbl_cmleader.mem_id WHERE tbl_cmleader.grp_id = 12 
and mdate = '2022-07-08'
```

I am getting **36** under column **NewConverts** buts that's not what I want

| MDate | MWeek | CWeek | NewConverts | cml_id | grp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 36 | 142 | 12 |

What I want is a **9** under column **NewConverts** as seen below

| MDate | MWeek | CWeek | NewConverts | cml_id | grp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-08 | 27 | 28 | 9 | 142 | 12 |

Please I need help on how to rewrite the query below to get the right result

```
SELECT mdate AS MDate, WEEK(mdate) AS MWeek,  WEEK(NOW()) AS CWeek, SUM(nconvt) AS 
NewConverts, tbl_cmreport.cml_id, tbl_cmleader.grp_id FROM tbl_cmreport INNER JOIN 
tbl_cmleader ON tbl_cmreport.mem_id = tbl_cmleader.mem_id WHERE tbl_cmleader.grp_id = 12 
and mdate = '2022-07-08'
```

Thank you in advance
Michael

Comment: Here is a link to download the SQL of the table I used above. Clicking it or copying it to paste in your browser will download the .SQL file  [https://www.mediafire.com/file/6nlg5gqrjqj7pnq/weeklyReport.sql/file]

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to look like, and how it is different than what you have? Do you want the number of New Converts in a given week? for a given day?

Comment: @Jerry Thank you for your response. Yes I want New Converts in a given week and for the illustration I gave, the New Convert value is supposed to be 9. 

I want the query result to produced in a table like this one


'MDate         | MWeek | CWeek  | NewConverts | cml_id | grp_id'
2022-07-08 |      27    |      28     |            9         |   142    |   12



Meaning it will show the MDate, MWeek, CWeek, NewConverts, cml_id and grp_id as seen in this table. 

Thank you

Comment: Can you just put a few rows from each of those tables here, and show what you want the result to look like? As a habit, I don't download files from strangers, and that really shouldn't be necessary here. I can see how to get 8 from the above result, but not 9.

Comment: @Jerry. Thank you so much. Based on your request, I entered the table with the row I want as my result in my detailed illustration above. The table below this sentence "What I want is a 9 under column NewConverts as seen below"  is the table that shows exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries will fail with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` enabled. It is not a good practice to disable it.

To get your desired result in the query which gives the final table that you want , you could apply an outer query doing the SUM

```
SELECT MDate,
       MWeek,
       CWeek,
       SUM(NewConverts) as tot_NewConverts,
       max(cml_id) as max_cml_id,
       grp_id
FROM ( 
       SELECT    mdate AS MDate, 
                 WEEK(mdate) AS MWeek,  
                 WEEK(NOW()) AS CWeek, 
                 NewConverts, 
                 tbl_cmleader.cml_id, 
                 tbl_cmleader.grp_id 
        FROM tbl_cmleader 
        WHERE tbl_cmleader.grp_id = 12 
        AND mdate = '2022-07-08' 
        GROUP BY MDate,MWeek,CWeek,cml_id,NewConverts,cml_id,grp_id
        ) as t1
GROUP BY MDate,MWeek,CWeek,grp_id;
```

*Note*,I used only one table so I removed the inner join clause.
max(cml_id) is  just to return the max cml_id, because of sql_mode=only_full_group_by disabled that returned value was arbitrary.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=355eb49ad446b63ee507ffe93be54440

Comment: Thank you so so much. You have saved me lost of hours and days of hard work. I am so grateful. Your query has saved the day. Based on what you did, I created a VIEW using the select statement 

'SELECT mdate AS MDate, WEEK(mdate) AS MWeek, WEEK(NOW()) AS CWeek, nconvt AS NewConverts, tbl_cmreport.cml_id, tbl_cmleader.grp_id FROM tbl_cmreport INNER JOIN tbl_cmleader ON tbl_cmreport.mem_id = tbl_cmleader.mem_id WHERE tbl_cmleader.grp_id = 12 and mdate = '2022-07-08' ORDER BY mdate DESC'

and then ran the VIEW statement to get exactly the same result you got. Thank you so much